# What are natural examples of non-relativizable proofs?

Tags: lo.logic, computational-complexity, computability-theory

As I understand it, a proof that P=NP or P≠NP would need to be non-relativizable (as in recursion theory oracles).

Virtually all proofs seem to be relativizable, though.

What are good examples of *non* relativizable proofs, of the sort that a P=NP/P≠NP proof would need to be, that are not trivial or contrived?

(I am not a recursion theorist, so please pardon the lack of citations.)

[xposted to [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/20511/what-are-natural-examples-of-non-relativizable-proofs) as suggested]

Comment: You might have more luck over on CSTheory, but at least one starting point: AFAIK, the proof of IP=PSPACE (and in particular, the inclusion of PSPACE in IP) doesn't relativize; it works by finding an interactive proof for a specific PSPACE-complete problem.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki xposted to cstheory per suggestion; thanks for the pointer.

Comment: I asked a similar question a few years ago: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55933/what-proofs-cannot-be-relativized.  Is it a duplicate, or are you asking something else?